# Why does Dan's hair change color?

Tags: minecraft-story-mode

In Minecraft story mode, episode 6. Some big Minecraft YouTubers make a guest appearance including Dan aka TheDiamondMinecart. Thought the episode Dan's hair changes color. Why is that?[image: here he has purple hair]

[image: here he has blue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a reference to DanTDM in **real life** dying his real hair.